# Passing values from view to controller and again from controller to view?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a controller suppose `a` and it has a function suppose `index()` where i passed data from my view suppose `b` using javascript like this:

```
var formURL = "<?php echo base_url();?>a/index/"+ $("#someid").val();
$.post(formURL).done(function(data){$("#something").html(data);
```

now i am receiving it in my controller like this:

```
public function index($somevalue= ""){
....
....
}
```

now after execution from the controller `a` i am again passing array values to the view `b` like this:

```
public function index($somevalue= ""){
....
....
$data['value1'] = $value1;
$data['value2'] = $value2;
$this->load->view('b', $data);
}
```

now when i am accessing the data in the view `b` like this:

```
<?php if (isset($value1)) {
echo $value1;
}?>
```

i am not getting the value of `value1`. what did i do wrong in this case???

Comment: In your controller check $data['value1'] have any value or not.

Comment: yes, in controller i can echo $data['value1'] and it is giving me the right value... but not in view....

Comment: what is the value of $data['value1']???

Comment: it is a regular string value....

Comment: it's a string like this "D123"...!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot lot better if you use `AJAX`. This is what it precisely does.

> AJAX request to controller i.e (sending datas to controller)
>       Get the `AJAX` result i.e (sending datas back to views)

and from client side you can update it.

You can get the form values like

```
var formDatas = $('#form').serialize();
```

Then make an ajax request like

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'url',
    data : {formdata : formDatas },
    success: function(result){
      //update the view with the result
    }

}
```